# Ajax Load with fade in

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i'm trying to load with a fade in an html with ajax. It loads but with no fade, I don't know what i'm doing wrong, here it's my code:

```
$("#artworks").click(function(){
// load artworks page
    $("#content").load("artworks.html"); function(){
    $(this).fadeIn("slow");
    });
});
```

it get's an error, what's my mistake?

Comment: Its not passed as a callback within load. http://api.jquery.com/load/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$("#artworks").click(function(){
    $("#content").load("artworks.html"); function(){
    $(this).fadeIn("slow");
    });
});
```

**SHOULD BE**

```
$("#artworks").click(function(){
    $("#content").load("artworks.html", function(){
      $(this).fadeIn("slow");
    });
});
```

**NOTE THE CHANGE OF `;` TO `,` AND THE MOVEMENT OF THE `)`**

Comment: Ain't no thang! (you could accept the answer if you **want**...)

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you mean:

```
$("#artworks").click(function(){
// load artworks page
    $("#content").load("artworks.html", function(){
        $(this).fadeIn("slow");
    });
});
```

This will only work if `#content` is invisible before the AJAX-load.