# Ajax replacing content and using fade

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I'm trying to replace the div with "demo" as the id, to the content of "newpage.html". This code works, although I'm just wondering how I'd be able to put a fade effect into it.

```
<button onclick="loadDoc()">Click here</button>     

function loadDoc() {
      var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
          document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
        }
      };
      xhttp.open("GET", "newpage.html", true);
      xhttp.send();
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jquery replacewith fade/animate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5248721/jquery-replacewith-fade-animate)

Comment: If you are willing to user jQuery, there are plenty of examples like this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12858904/ajax-load-with-fade-in

Comment: And here is some stuff to you could add to your example without jQuery: http://www.chrisbuttery.com/articles/fade-in-fade-out-with-javascript/

Answer (score 0):

Remove

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
```

Add this code instead

also change '`content`' to '`xhttp.responseText`'

```
$('#demo').fadeOut('slow', function() {
    $('#demo').html(content);
    $('#demo').fadeIn('slow');
});
```

Finally you have to add jquery library to perform **`'FadeIn'`**

Jquery Library link [Jquery](https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js)

You have to add below code to your html header section.

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Comment: The question is using plain javascript and is not tagged with jQuery, so don't forget to mention to the OP to add jQuery, as this code won't work without.

Comment: @LGSon Sorry for that.I think he might be know how to use Jquery

Comment: Be careful assuming someone know a certain technology, even if it is a common one, some just don't.